# I'm after a GWT CellTree example that uses EditTextCell

Tags: java, gwt

I'm looking for GWT CellTree examples that use a EditTextCell instead of the normal AbstractCell and associated renderers. It would seem EditTextCell doesn't support Types and expects all values to be string, so I'm unsure how to provide a data provider that is still used for the CellTree but is also able to be rendered and edited by the EditTextCell.

I think a simple editable example of a CellTree would be all I'd need to see... or maybe even a hint at where I'm looking at this incorrectly.

Comment: I think the issue is that CellTree needs nodes that retain the parent-child relationship and are thus able to be of any generic type to allow for that - unfortunately EditTextCell requires nodes of type String only, so I'm wondering how you'd use them together?

Comment: I can see only a solution whereby you can only use EditTextCell on the last node, and thus that might be ok, it kinda limits the degree you can edit and modify information within a CellTree. When compared with CellTable, it seems a little limited.